# Merging two partial (jointly overdetermined) sets of ordering information

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, partial-ordering

I have a web app with data in a grid. The user can reorder the columns, and the server can change which columns exist. I would like to save the user's column order in a cookie and restore it on page load.

More formally, I have two arrays of unique IDs (strings) called `user_columns` and `server_columns`. I would like to reorder `server_columns` such that I respect *all* of the ordering information from `user_columns`, and as much from `server_columns` as possible. How do I do this? What's a reasonable formal definition of "as much as possible"?

My analysis so far:

One aspect of the problem is trivial: if the server removes some columns, delete the corresponding entries from `user_columns`. Any information about the ordering of columns which are no longer there is moot. The problem then becomes one of merging two potentially conflicting sets of ordering information.

This corresponds to a family of problems from voting theory: given a set of ballots, each of which contains a partial order between the candidates, produce a complete ordering of the candidates which in some sense reflects the ballots.

This leads me to think that I might get a workable solution by applying e.g. the [Schulze Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schulze_method) or [Ranked Pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranked_Pairs) to a sufficiently rigged set of ballots based on `user_columns` and `server_columns`. For UX reasons, breaking ties by inserting new columns last (to the right) seems like a good idea to me.

Does this sound like it's on the right track?

Note also that we can consider three kinds of comparisons: A and B are both in `user_columns`, one of them is, or none of them are. The former and latter kinds are easily resolved (refer to `user_columns` and `server_columns`, respectively); the one in the middle, and its interactions with the latter, are the tricky parts.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932601/sequence-merging-between-two-semi-synchronized-lists and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352212/how-to-merge-a-collection-of-ordered-preferences

Comment: What's the language you want to implement this in?

Comment: @Ivarpoiss: javascript

Comment: Please clarify the question. Can the server reorder columns as well or just change the set of columns? Because in the former case, why do you mention voting theory at all? There's no voting necessary if only one side has an ordering at all

Comment: Both `user_columns` and `server_columns` are arrays, and the server can change the order of columns, i.e. if A and B both occur in `server_columns` in two consecutive page loads, they can occur in two different orders.  The more interesting property, I think, is that `user_columns` and `server_columns` can disagree in a single page load, but in either case I think the answer is "yes" :)

Comment: Would you be happy with an algorithm that minimizes the inversions with respect to `server_columns` and respects `user_columns` completely (zero inversions w.r.t. `user_columns`)? Because that how I interpret the question.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say we have *C* columns, numbered from *1* to *C*. We have two sequences sequences of columns, *U = u<sub>1</sub>, u<sub>2</sub>, ... u<sub>n</sub>*  and *S = s<sub>1</sub>, s<sub>2</sub>, ... s<sub>m</sub>*. We want to find a permutation *P* of *S*, such that *P* has no inversions with regard to *U* and a minimal number of inversions with regard to *S*.

We can show that there is such an optimal *P* which is an interleaving of *U ∩ S* and *S \ U*. By "interleaving" I mean that *P* has no inversions with regard to *U ∩ S* or *S \ U*.

We can apply [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to find the optimal interleaving: Let A = (a<sub>i</sub>) = U ∩ S and B = (b<sub>j</sub>) = S \ U. Let *f(i,j)* be the number of inversions w.r.t. *S* of the optimal interleaving of the prefixes a<sub>1...i</sub> of A and b<sub>1...j</sub> of B. The idea is very similar to the [longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#LCS_function_defined) DP algorithm. We have the recurrence

```
f(0,j) = 0 for all j >= 0
f(i,0) = f(i-1, 0) + sum(k=1 to i-1, [1 if A[i] appears before A[k] in S])
f(i,j) = min(f(i-1, j) + sum(k=1 to i-1, [1 if A[i] appears before A[k] in S])
                       + sum(k=1 to j, [1 if A[i] appears before B[k] in S]),
             f(i, j-1) + sum(k=1 to i, [1 if B[j] appears before A[k] in S])
                       + sum(k=1 to j-1, [1 if B[j] appears before B[k] in S]))
```

I used the notation `[1 if X]` here to denote the value `1`, if X is true and `0`, if X is false.

The matrix `f` can be built in time O(|A|^2 * |B|^2). The minimal cost (number of inversions w.r.t. S) will be *f(|A|, |B|)*.

We can reconstruct the optimal permutation using the DP matrix as well: We build it from back to front. We start with the tuple (i,j) = (|A|, |B|) and at every step depending on which of the two options is minimum in the DP transition, we know whether we need to put A[i] or B[j] to the front of the permutation. Then we proceed with (i-1, j) or (i, j-1) depending on which we choose.

[Here is an implementation of the algorithm](http://jsfiddle.net/BHU5H/2/), please excuse my lack of JS skills.

Comment: Regarding the interleaving proof: assume we have *b₂, aᵢ, ..., aⱼ, b₁* as part of the solution with *b₁* inverted relative to *b₂*.  Let *Inv(1)* be the number of inversions between *b₁* and *aᵢ..aⱼ*, and *Inv(2)* likewise.  If *Inv(1) ≤ Inv(2)* then *aᵢ, ..., aⱼ, b₁, b₂* has fewer inversions than the original(*new Inv(2) = old Inv(1) ≤ old Inv(2)*, and we fixed the *b₁/b₂* inversion), and similarly in reverse if *Inv(2) ≤ Inv(1)*. Since swapping adjacent out-of-order *b*-elements lowers the inversion count, the solution has the elements of *b* in order.  QED.  Correct?

Comment: @JonasKölker Very good, that is actually very similar to the proof idea I had in mind and it is a very compact formulation of it. I like it

Comment: @JonasKölker Actually I think swapping b1 and b2 can cost you one additional inversion, but since you also decrement it by putting b1 and b2 in order you get at least an equally good permutation. Or to be more precise, `new Inv(2) = old Inv(1) <= old Inv(2)` doesn't necessarily hold if I'm not mistaken, but it's a bit too late here for me to be sure about that right now

Comment: @JonasKölker By the way in case you're interested, the recurrence can probably be solved in O(|A| * |B|)

Comment: I'd be very interested in both a fix of my proof and a faster algorithm :)

Comment: @Jonas The algorithmic part is easier: E.g. Let `g(x,K) = sum(k=1 to K, [1 if x appears before A[k] in S])`. Then we have `g(x,K) = g(x,K-1) + [1 if x appears before A[K] in S]`, so we can compute all the sums in O(1). You can answer "X appears before Y in S" queries in O(1) by precomputing the ranks of elements in S

Answer (score 1):

One definition that might be reasonable is to minimize the number of inversions relative to the server's order, subject to the constraint that the restriction to the columns in common of the two orders be equal. I don't know offhand an algorithm to minimize this objective.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable definition.   I suspect that the Schulze Method or Ranked Pairs can achieve this, but I haven't though enough about it.

Comment: I think we can just use DP to optimally interleave the client column set with the server column set excluding the client columns

Comment: @NiklasB. I thought that there might be something like that. I had to rush out the door five minutes after I started this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This relates to [Niklas B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22573767/58668):

**Theorem**: Consider a sequence *S = s₁, …, sₙ* of some orderet set  (e.g. integers).  If *i < j* and *sᵢ > sⱼ*, then swapping *sᵢ* and *sⱼ* decreases the number of inversions—that is, let *S' = s₁, …, sᵢ₋₁, sⱼ, sᵢ₊₁, …, sⱼ₋₁, sᵢ, sⱼ₊₁, …, sₙ*; then *S'* has fewer inversions than *S*.

Intuitively stated: if two elements are out of order and you swap them, you're closer to having a sorted list.

**Proof**: Observe that the only elements that have a different relative order in *S* and *S'* are (*sᵢ*, *sⱼ*), (*sᵢ*, *sₖ*) and (*sⱼ*, *sₖ*) for each *k* where *i < k < j*.  We know that (*sᵢ*, *sⱼ*) is an inversion in *S* but not *S'*, so consider *sₖ* for some such *k*.

Either *sₖ < sⱼ < sᵢ* or *sⱼ < sₖ < sᵢ* or *sⱼ < sᵢ < sₖ* (we assume the elements of *S* to be unique).

In the first case, (*sᵢ*, *sₖ*) is an inversion in *S* and (*sⱼ*, *sₖ*) is an inversion in *S'*.  In the second case, (*sᵢ*, *sₖ*) and (*sⱼ*, *sₖ*) are inversions in *S* but not in *S'*.  In the third case, (*sⱼ*, *sₖ*) is an inversion in *S* and (*sᵢ*, *sₖ*).  These are all the changes in inversions.

In each case, the number of inversions in *S'* is either the same as that in *S* or it is smaller.  Recall that (*sᵢ*, *sⱼ*) got fixed from *S* to *S'*, and we get the desired result. ■

Thus, if we have *a₁, bᵢ, …, bⱼ, a₂* with each *a* ∈ *S* \ *U* and each *b* ∈ *U* ∩ *S* and *a₁* > *a₂* and we swap *a₁* and *a₂*, getting *a₂, bᵢ, …, bⱼ, a₁*, the inversion count is lower.  Since such swaps only rearrange elements of *S* \ *U* and not those of *U* ∩ *S*, any solution which has zero inversions on *U* ∩ *S* and (subject to that) a minimal number of inversions on *S* \ *U* must make all such swaps.

Ergo: the elements of *S* \ *U* must occur in order, and thus the solution is an interleaving of *U* ∩ *S* and *S* \ *U*.

Comment: Kudos for doing the proof on your own, I really appreciate that :) It looks good to me, I had something wrong yesterday when I thought there was a problem. My approach was something like this: Let's say we have `b2 ai, ..., aj b1` as a substring of the permutation and we have `X < b1 < Y < b2 < Z` in S, where `X`, `Y` and `Z` represent subsets of `ai, ..., aj`. Then `b2 ai, ..., aj b1` has `1 + |X| + 2|Y| + |Z|` inversions, `b1 b2 ai, ..., aj` has `2|X| + |Z|` and `ai, ..., aj b1 b2` has `2|Z| + |Y|`. So depending on whether `|X| < Z|` or not we can always do strictly better using one of those